# cassandra - Take snapshot to different location

Tags: linux, cassandra, backup

I want to take **Cassandra backup at every 1hr interval** and move it to Shared location.

Cassandra taking the snapshot in the default location, how can I take the snapshot on ***/opt/backup*** location?

Comment: Okay then, start your journey from here.. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAboutSnapshots.html  . Here you'll find a detailed/step by step explanation of what you are seeking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't (with snapshots).

`nodetool snapshot -t <tag> <keyspace>` is a quite simple tool - it just creates hard links for every file in your keyspace data directories to `snapshots/<tag>`.

Since these are hard links they have to be on the same filesystem. Benefit of those hard links is that a snapshot is quite fast and doesn't consume additional disk space initially (when sstables got compacted / deleted the files remain in the snapshot).

If you want those backups in a different location use `-t <tag>` while creating your snapshot. I made up a demo with `demosnapshot` and a simple script (not fully elaborated but shows the idea:

```
$ cat cassandrabackup.sh
#!/bin/bash

TAG=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
BACKUP_LOC=/tmp/backup/`hostname`
KEYSPACE=demokeyspace

echo creating snapshot $TAG
nodetool snapshot -t $TAG $KEYSPACE

echo sync to backup location $BACKUP_LOC
find /var/lib/cassandra -type f -path "*snapshots/$TAG*" -printf %P\\0 | rsync -avP --files-from=- --from0 /var/lib/cassandra/ $BACKUP_LOC

echo removing snapshot $TAG
nodetool clearsnapshot -t $TAG
```

The script creates a snaphot with a specific tag (datetime), rsyncs the contents to a backup location and then removes the snapshot. If `KEYSPACE` is not defined all keyspaces are backuped.

Result is like this:

```
$ ./cassandrabackup.sh
creating snapshot 20170823132936
Requested creating snapshot(s) for [demokeyspace] with snapshot name [20170823132936] and options {skipFlush=false}
Snapshot directory: 20170823132936
sync to backup location /tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld
building file list ...
6 files to consider
data1/
data1/demokeyspace/
data1/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/
data1/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/
data1/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/20170823132936/
data1/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/20170823132936/manifest.json
             13 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/6)

sent 305 bytes  received 50 bytes  710.00 bytes/sec
total size is 13  speedup is 0.04
removing snapshot 20170823132936
Requested clearing snapshot(s) for [all keyspaces] with snapshot name [20170823132936]
$ ifjke@fsca01:~$ find /tmp/backup/
/tmp/backup/
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data2
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data2/demokeyspace
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data2/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data2/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data2/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/20170823125951
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data2/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/20170823125951/manifest.json
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data2/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/20170823130014
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data2/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/20170823130014/manifest.json
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data1
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data1/demokeyspace
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data1/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data1/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data1/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/20170823132936
/tmp/backup/host1.domain.tld/data1/demokeyspace/demotable-0bbb579087ef11e7aa786377cd3ba823/snapshots/20170823132936/manifest.json
$
```

As I did that error by myself in the past - include hostname in the backups ;)

Apart from that there is also an incremental backup feature in cassandra:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupIncremental.html

Comment: This is cool, is this possible to backup all keyspaces at once

Comment: Simply dont provide a keyspace at all - then all keyspaces are snapshotted at once.

Comment: huh,, Thanks Dude :)

Comment: How can I use the same script for Incremental backup?